# How do I assign a class to all table cells containing a particular string?

Tags: php, html, string, html-table

I am working on a project for a company I just started working for and have hit a roadblock with this data visualizer I have been assigned to create. I am pulling in information from a MySQL database using PHP and embedding the data into an HTML-CSS table.

Four particular columns of this table will always contain one of the following strings: 'red', 'green', 'yellow' and 'grey'. I am trying to write a script in PHP that looks for all table cells containing the string 'green', for example, and assigns that table cell a class called 'green_circle'. My plan is to then put a green circle (a .png, most likely) in all cells with that class. I hope to do this so the information is more efficiently visible. I want to do this for each of those four colors.

Here is what the table-body looks like:

```
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                                while ($row6 = mysql_fetch_assoc($orl_error)) {
                                    echo '
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>'.$row6["project"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row6["participant"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row6["reel"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row6["machine"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row6["qc_gsr"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row6["qc_hr"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row6["qc_acz"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row6["qc_bre"].'</td>
                                        </tr> ';
                                    }
                                ?>
                        </tbody>
```

The strings 'green', 'yellow', 'red', and 'grey' are always found in the 4 cells with names beginning with 'qc_', so qc_gsr, qc_hr, qc_acz, qc_bre. The other 4 columns never contain any of the color strings. I hope the information I have provided is clear enough for someone to figure out this problem I have been having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$keys = array('qc_gsr', 'qc_hr', 'qc_acz', 'qc_bre');
while ($row6 = mysql_fetch_assoc($orl_error)) {
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$row6["project"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row6["participant"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row6["reel"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row6["machine"].'</td>';
        foreach($keys AS $key){
            echo '<td class="'.$row6[$key].'">'.$row6[$key].'</td>';
        }
    echo '</tr> ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jessica, I am kind of a rookie developer so a more thorough answer would be even more appreciated. If, rather than inserting the key name of the column, I want to insert a circle with the color of the string that is contained in that cell, what would I want to do?

Comment: Would javascript be more useful for this task?

Comment: Then just have PHP generate the HTML needed for an image. Assuming you've already created your 4 images.

Comment: I have, can you run me through how I might do that if the image to replace the string 'green' is say green_circle.png

Comment: echo '`<td class="'.$row6[$key].'"><img src="'.$row6[$key].'_circle.png"></td>';`

Comment: But then you don't even need the class part. You talked about CSS classes, I assumed you'd made the class use the image already.

Comment: Jessica, wow! The simplest solution of all was to save the image files so that they started with the string! this is why I love programming! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy task, to say the least, but I think you can accomplish it with a little good array based iteration, and the use of the [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), and [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) functions.  Basically, the goal is to make an associative array that links the keywords as the key, and the desired classes as the values.  I then join them to make a regular expression of the form `#\b(key1|key2|key3)\b#i`, which will search the string for any of the keywords.  Using the `$matches` argument for  [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), I get the actual matched text, and use the [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function to convert it to lower case, and the `$classes` array to convert it to the desired class.

```
<tbody>
    <?php
        $keys = array('project'
            , 'participant'
            , 'reel'
            , 'machine'
            , 'qc_gsr'
            , 'qc_hr'
            , 'qc_acz'
            , 'qc_bre'
        );
        $classes = array('yellow' => 'yellow_square'
            , 'green' => 'green_circle'
        );
        $class_keys = '#\b(' . implode('|', array_keys($classes)) . ')\b#i';
        while ($row6 = mysql_fetch_assoc($orl_error)) {
            echo '<tr>';
                foreach($keys as $key){
                    $class = '';
                    if(preg_match($class_keys, $row6[$key], $match)){
                        $class = $classes[strtolower($matches[0])];
                    }
                    echo "<td class=\"$class\" >".$row6[$key].'</td>';
                }
            echo '</tr> ';
         }
     ?>
</tbody>
```

I did make a few assumptions, for the sake of brevity:

- I assumed that your `qc_` fields would only contain one of the necessary keywords.
- I assumed that the necessary keywords were on there own (i.e. that you wouldn't want `yellowbellied' to match)

I did not assume an order to your existing $row6 array.  Though there's likely some order that is implied by the select statement, which would eliminate the `$keys` variable, and allow you to change `foreach($keys as $key)` to `foreach ($row6 as $key => $value)`, and you can thereafter change any `$row6[$key]` to just `value`.

**EDIT**:  To insert the img tag directly, do something more like this:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
        $keys = array('project'
            , 'participant'
            , 'reel'
            , 'machine'
            , 'qc_gsr'
            , 'qc_hr'
            , 'qc_acz'
            , 'qc_bre'
        );
        $images = array('yellow' => '/path/to/yellow_square.png'
            , 'green' => '/path/to/green_circle.png'
        );
        $image_keys = '#\b(' . implode('|', array_keys($images)) . ')\b#i';
        while ($row6 = mysql_fetch_assoc($orl_error)) {
            echo '<tr>';
                foreach($keys as $key){
                    echo '<td>';
                    if(preg_match($image_keys, $row6[$key], $match)){
                        echo '<img src="'.$images[strtolower($matches[0])].'" /> ';
                    }
                    echo $row6[$key].'</td>';
                }
            echo '</tr> ';
         }
     ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: now if my image file is called green_circle.png for the green string replacement, how might I proceed. qc_ fields DO only contain one of the keywords, and the keywords are on their own

Comment: @user2479631  That's not really what you asked in your question.  But I'll humor you.  You can either do it through php directly, or through css3 with the `before` pseudo-element.  If you want to do it with css3, I think it's outside the scope of this problem. I'll update with new PHP shortly.